# Django 2 stops working after deploying on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-2.0

I'm working on a project using Django(2) in which I have some models and the application was working correctly on my local system.

But when I have deployed this application to Heroku, it starts returning an error as:

> column core_votingvalueshistory.value1 does not exist LINE 1: SELECT
>   "core_votingvalueshistory"."id", "core_votingvalueshi...
>                                                   ^ HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "core_votingvalueshistory.value".

Here's my model which causes the problem:

```
class VotingValuesHistory(models.Model):
    # id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    value1 = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    value2 = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    value3 = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    value4 = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    value5 = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    score1 = models.CharField(choices=VOTE_CHOICES, max_length=20)
    score2 = models.CharField(choices=VOTE_CHOICES, max_length=20)
    score3 = models.CharField(choices=VOTE_CHOICES, max_length=20)
    score4 = models.CharField(choices=VOTE_CHOICES, max_length=20)
    score5 = models.CharField(choices=VOTE_CHOICES, max_length=20)
    user = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    group = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='notingroup')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and it's also pointing the view where I'm making a query to the objects as:

**From `views.py`:**

```
v1 = VotingValuesHistory.objects.all().filter()
        for item in v1:
            if item.group == groupname:
                if item.score1 == 'disaster':
                    numscore_disaster += 1
                elif item.score1 == 'meh':
                    numscore_meh += 1
                else:
                    numscore_helpful += 1
```

I have tried `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands using:

```
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations

heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Have you committed all of your local migrations and deployed a version that includes them to Heroku? (There should never be any reason to run `manage.py makemigrations` on Heroku. This only needs to be done locally. You _should_ run `manage.py migrate` locally, on Heroku, and anywhere else you may be running this code.)

Comment: yes, I have rum `makemigrations` and `migrate` command on local and include all migrations into the commit.

Comment: If you create a brand new copy of your app locally (e.g. by cloning from your Git repository) and run migrations, do you get the expected columns in your database?

Comment: yes, I'm getting all the columns in my local db.

Comment: Even with a brand new, clean installation and database?